# Is there a CacheEntryExpiredListener for Caffeine Cache?

Tags: java, caching, caffeine

I know `Cache2k` having a `CacheEntryExpiredListener` that is only triggered if a cache entry self-expires (not when being invalidated explicit).

```
 Cache<String, Object> cache = Cache2kBuilder.of(String.class, Object.class)
    .addListener(
        (CacheEntryExpiredListener<String, Object>) (cache, entry)
              -> handleExpired(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();
```

Question: how could I achieve the same using `caffeine` cache implementation?

Comment: See `RemovalListener` and it’s `RemovalCause` param.

Comment: @BenManes is the remove listener called before or after the entry is removed from cache? I'm asking because I want to write the expired entries into a database. And want to make sure I'm not having a state where an entry is not present in the caffeine anymore, but also not yet persisted...

Comment: Oh. [RemovalListener](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Removal) is after while [CacheWriter](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Writer) is during.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the hint from @Ben Manes:

```
Caffeine.newBuilder()
        .removalListener((key, value, cause) -> {
            if (cause.wasEvicted()) System.out.printf("key=%s, value=%s", key, value);
        })
        .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
```