# Perform action on expiry with Caffeine on Java

Tags: java, caching, caffeine-cache

I want to create a cache like so

```
Cache<String, File> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .maximumSize(100)
                .build();
```

That i will populate with a temporary file like so,

```
File f = File.createTempFile("jobid_", ".json");
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(f);
fileWriter.write("text values 123");
fileWriter.close();


cache.put("jobid", f);
```

Now after 1 minute I understand that `cache.getIfPresent("jobid")` will return `null`, my question is that is there some way in which I can trigger another task when this entry expires - deleting the temporary file itself.

Any alternative solution works as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045949/is-there-a-cacheentryexpiredlistener-for-caffeine-cache

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to fluffy.

To implement the same, simple use the removalListener.

For my use case:

```
Cache<String, File> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
    .removalListener((String key, File file, RemovalCause cause) -> {
      file.delete();
    })
    .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .maximumSize(100)
    .build();
```

solves the problem.